can I use the slug from a different urls.py file?
I'm trying to access a slug field from a different urls.py file, and I'm getting this error
FieldError at /new-api/tournaments/fifa-world-cup/teams/
Unsupported lookup 'custom_url' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.

I'm wondering if the reason I'm getting this error is because you cant do that or if it's another reason
I have 2 files for urls, one includes the other in it,
urls.py (tournament)
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.getNewTournaments, name="tournaments"),
    path("<slug:custom_url>/", views.getNewTournament, name="tournament"),
    path("create/", views.postNewTournament, name="post-tournament"),
    path("<slug:custom_url>/teams/", include("teams.urls"), name="tournament-teams"),
]

urls.py (teams)
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.teams.as_view(), name="teams"),
]

Here are the views.py files
views.py (tournaments)
@api_view(["GET"])
def getNewTournaments(request):
    tournaments = NewTournament.objects.all()
    serializer = NewTournamentSerializer(tournaments, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

views.py (teams)
class teams(APIView):
    def get(self, request, custom_url):
        teams = Team.objects.filter(tournament__custom_url=custom_url)
        serializer = TeamSerializer(teams, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


This looks like DRF and I'm not yet familiar with DRF. Perhaps, you are trying to map your app urls to views before including it. I'm thinking path("<slug:custom_url>/teams/", include("teams.urls"), name="tournament-teams"), should be included in your project urls.py, just below path(admin/, admin.site.urls),

@16171413 I edited the post to add the DRF tag... sorry about that haha.
But I edited the teams api to be like this
 class teams(APIView):     def get(self, request, custom_url):         # teams = Team.objects.filter(tournament__custom_url=custom_url)         teams = Team.objects.all()         serializer = TeamSerializer(teams, many=True)         return Response(serializer.data)
And it let me see the data, so I'm assuming the problem is with the view trying to get the data

Note that create/ will never be called, since that is also a slug, so it will take the second path, not the third.

@willeM_VanOnsem so should I move it above the slug url?
Also thanks for letting me know about that

@willeM_VanOnsem so I just tested it and your right, thanks for letting me know about that

So I realized that my error was my model for the teams had the past model version of the tournaments
Old
class Team(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

New
class Team(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(NewTournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

